# Is returning worn clothing or shoes considered stealing?

Tags: halacha, transactions, gezel-stealing

Suppose one purchased, say, a pair of shoes. If he changed his mind about them after wearing them outside, is it halachically permissible to return them to the store after they get creases and slight rubbing signs on the sole?

What is the halachah for stores that take back items without questions?

What is the halachah for stores that don't take back worn items?

With regular clothing (pants, skirts, shirts and sweaters), the possibility of creating signs of wear is minimal after wearing it for only a few times. With shoes the signs are more noticeable.

Comment: I think the store's policy would be material in this case. Please [edit] your question to indicate whether the store a) doesn't have a clear return policy, b) has a return policy that clearly includes shoes worn outside, c) has a return policy that clearly excludes shoes worn outside, or d) some of the above.

Comment: You mean assuming the shop would accept them back for full credit if they knew, or do you mean returning them without mentioning that he wore them?